# How do version control systems generate original file with a long history so fast?

Tags: java, version-control, diff, patch

I am working on a simple text-file versioning system in java. When commit command is used I calculate the diff between the latest version and the last version committed and store it. I have written the code to make the diff file and to regenerate the original file. The problem, here, I feel is that for a very large commit history I will have to recreate the last committed version and then use diff. This will also be the case when I checkout a previous version of the file. So using my algorithm I will have to use my first commit(which has all original data and not diff) and then keep on applying regenerate algorithm for next diff. This would take very long. I am looking forward to making this faster and efficient. Can you tell me how do I do this?

Also not all diff are calculated in the same order that is specified.That is if I have two files, `file1` and `file2`, I calculate diff like this: `diff(file1, file2);` and `diff(file2, file1);`. And I keep only the file which is smaller in size. The other file, I delete it. I would like to know if this is a good approach?

I only need some way to approach this problem. Not the source code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's say you have a huge file, 10000's of lines, and you have many commits on this file.

In the case you want to go back/forward more than one commit, you shouldn't apply each commit to the huge file. Instead, starting from the first commit, create a diff file with the line numbers. Because while 1st commit adding line X, 2nd commit could be deleting line X. This way you don't have to deal with the file twice. If you only keep a diff file with the line numbers, at the last commit you can start applying the diff.

There are all sorts of optimizations you can make on top of this but based on your explanation, not recreating the file is the most important one.

Comment: Okay, So I create a diff file of those diff files. Yeah, I think that would work. Thanks.